# Repeating capture group in a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

What would be the best way to parse the following string in Java using a single regex?

String:
`someprefix foo=someval baz=anotherval baz=somethingelse`

I need to extract `someprefix`, `someval`, `anotherval` and `somethingelse`. The string always contains a prefix value (`someprefix` in the example) and can have from 0 to 4 key-value pairs (`foo=someval baz=anotherval baz=somethingelse` in the example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for capturing your intended text,

```
(?<==|^)\w+
```

Which captures a word that is preceded by either an `=` character or is at `^` start of string.

Sample java code for same,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<==|^)\\w+");
String s = "someprefix foo=someval baz=anotherval baz=somethingelse";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Prints,

```
someprefix
someval
anotherval
somethingelse
```

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B5OSDc/1)**